# How to display mouse position as tooltip in OpenLayers-2?

Tags: openlayers-2, javascript

I want map coordinates as mouse over effect in OpenLayers. I am using the following code. However it is showing pixel coordinates:

```
    map.events.register("mousemove", map, function(e) {      
      var position = e.map.x + e.xy.y;
      OpenLayers.Util.getElement("tooltip").innerHTML = position 
    });
```

Comment: wow 7k views and only 4 up votes?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

you can convert pixels to lat/long with the help of [getLonLatFromPixel()](http://dev.openlayers.org/docs/files/OpenLayers/Map-js.html#OpenLayers.Map.getLonLatFromPixel) function.

See also openlayers [FAQ](http://trac.osgeo.org/openlayers/wiki/FrequentlyAskedQuestions#HowdoIgettheLonLatfromapixelorfromthecurrentpositionofthemouse).

Answer (score 11):

To add to simo's answer... here's an example:

```
map.events.register("mousemove", map, function (e) {
    var position = e.map.getLonLatFromViewPortPx(e.xy);
    OpenLayers.Util.getElement("tooltip").innerHTML = "<label>Latitude: " + position.lat + "</label><br/><label>Longitude: " + position.lon + "</label>";
});
```

You may need to transform from Mercator to Geographic as i did... if so:

```
var position = e.map.getLonLatFromViewPortPx(e.xy).transform(new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:900913"), new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"));
```

Answer (score 5):

As of Openlayers 2.12 the following approach works for accessing the coordinates from hovering:

```
map.events.register("mousemove", map, function (e) {            
var point = map.getLonLatFromPixel( this.events.getMousePosition(e) )     
    console.log(point.lon, point.lat)
});
```

Answer (score 1):

In Openlayers 2.13, you can do it like:

```
map.addControl(
    new OpenLayers.Control.MousePosition({
        prefix: 'Coords: ',
        separator: ' | ',
        numDigits: 2,
        emptyString: 'Mouse not over map'
    })
);
```