# Dynamically displaying mouse position (coordinates) while drawing polygon?

Tags: openlayers-2

I would like to dynamically display coordinates of the point, using label for example, while drawing polygon. I did so far:

```
var fromProjection = new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326");
var toProjection = new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:900913");
...
map.events.register("mousemove", map, function(evt){
    if (polygon.active) {
        var position = map.getLonLatFromPixel(this.events.getMousePosition(evt));
        var g = position.transform(toProjection, fromProjection);
        var f = formatLonlats(g);//my owny function which displays coordinates as: x1 deg y1 min z1 sec N, x2 deg y2 min z2 sec E (and here its decimal values)
        console.log(">> coordinates = " + f);
    }      
});
```

It's working for console, but how can I display a label with "f" value while drawing polygon?

Answer (score 1):

you can replace

```
console.log(">> coordinates = " + f);
```

by this line  if we suppose that  "coordiantes" is the id of your label

```
OpenLayers.Util.getElement("coordiantes").innerHTML = f ;
```

you can see also this [ISSUE](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/15540/how-to-display-mouse-position-as-tooltip-in-openlayers)

you can also use the MousePosition Control if you want to show mouse position inside the map

```
map.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.MousePosition());
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I have already did it. I was not precise with my question. My OpenLayers.Control.MousePosition is on the map and works fine - but it is static. OpenLayers.Util.getElement("coordiantes").innerHTML = f - also will be static. I would like to have "mobile" label which is attached to polygon point while drawing.

Comment: in this case you can use jQuery and use the attribute tooltip   
I don't know if it works but try to replace console.log(">> coordinates = " + f);  by 
     $('#map_div_id').tooltip({
     track: true, 
    delay: 0,   
    opacity: 0.95, 
    left: -120 ,
    content: f 
    });

Comment: and add this css class just to let this tooltip more pretty .ui-tooltip
{
    font-size:10pt;
    font-family:Calibri;
}

Comment: of course if you are using JQuery

Comment: Thank you once again for your efforts to help me. I have attached jquery-1.8.2.min.js, but I'm getting: 'Type error: ${...}.tooltip is not a function.'

Comment: here the [documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/tooltip/#option-tooltipClass) where I found this function I think this function is added in the version 1.9 of JQuery