# log the coordinates of mouse poisition

Tags: openlayers-2

Is there a simple way that I can access the coordinates (according to my used projection) and make them visible, like

```
console.log(currentX+" "+currentY);
```

?

Comment: This is what I found:

http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/51881/37728

Answer (score 2):

This example should do what you want:
http://openlayers.org/en/master/examples/mouse-position.html

It's an OpenLayers Control ( http://dev.openlayers.org/docs/files/OpenLayers/Control/MousePosition-js.html) , but you can get it to point at specific objects on the screen so it gets written there instead.

```
var mousePositionControl = new ol.control.MousePosition({
  coordinateFormat: ol.coordinate.createStringXY(4),
  projection: 'EPSG:4326',

  // comment the following two lines to have the mouse position
  // be placed within the map.

  className: 'custom-mouse-position',
  target: document.getElementById('mouse-position'),
  undefinedHTML: '&nbsp;'
});
```